# Pptp балансировка трафика

Tags: debian, ubuntu

в chap-secrets 9 пользователей как поделить поровну между ними траффик ( tc? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это тема для другой сети знаний, могу сказать только, что вам нужен шейпер для раздела трафика http://habrahabr.ru/post/73257/